# select element where the id=selectedId

Tags: angular

```
this.route.params.
    subscribe(params=>{this.selectedid=+params['id']});
    this.httpClient
    .get("http://localhost:8010/patients/"+this.selectedid)
    .subscribe(data=>{this.patient=data});
```

I try to catch the selected element in use the correct url but that doesn't work.
So i use this url: "http://localhost:8010/patients/" whith this.listpatient=data

and i try to get the patient where patient.id=patient.selectedid

may be i can make that in the html:

```
<ul class="list-group" 
*ngFor="let patient of listpatient"
?????? WHERE PATIENT.ID ==PATIENT.SELECTEDID????   >
  <li>{{patient.id}}</li>
  <li>{{patient.nom}}</li>
  <li>{{patient.prenom}}</li>
```

Comment: j'aimerais afficher les détails par patient, j'aimerais donc les afficher dans le composant html. L'opération me paraissait simple en le gettant par id via la requete http mais l'erreur m'affiche qu'il n'y a pas d'id par exemple pour l'objet getté

Answer (score 0):

You're subscribing to `this.route.params` and calling `this.httpClient.get` parallely. Due to that, your `this.selectedid` won't set and even before that, your http get call will be made.

Move the Http GET call inside the subscribe block for `route.params`, right below `this.selectedid = +params['id'];`.

Something like this:

```
this.route.params.
subscribe(params => {
  this.selectedid = +params['id'];
  this.httpClient
    .get("http://localhost:8010/patients/" + this.selectedid)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.patient = data
    });
});
```

Comment: it  say me that id is undefined for patient, but my http request give me that: {"id":1,"nom":"Ben Baba","prenom":"Omar","dateNaiss":"11/02/1999","tel":"0481-123-456","numChbre":null,"

Comment: There are quite a lot of unknowns here. I'd appreciate it if you could create a reproducible example for me using [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com/fork/angular) and share it across.